# UICollectionView & custom UICollectionReusableView not works

Tags: ios, xib, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

I'm trying to use custom `UICollectionReusableView` (which has own class and XIB) in my `UICollectionView` header. But after fetching data in the place of header I have nothing.

My steps:

1. Registering class in **viewDidLoad**:

   ```
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[CollectionViewHeader class] 
     forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader 
     withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView"];
   ```
2. Trying to show:

   ```
   - (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
   UICollectionReusableView *reusableView = nil;

   if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
       CollectionViewHeader *collectionHeader = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];

       NSInteger section = [indexPath section];
       id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [fetchRecipes sections][section];
       collectionHeader.headerLabel.text = @"bla-bla-bla";

       reusableView = collectionHeader;
   }

   return reusableView;
   }
   ```

Can anybody tell me what's wrong? ) 
Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 14):

I think you are adding label to the xib. So you need to **registerNib:** for the header view instead of **registerClass:**

Answer (score 10):

1. Register Your header nib/xib in the viewDidLoad section.

   ```
   [self.collectionView registerNib:  [UINib nibWithNibName:@"headerCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"headerCell"];
   ```
2. Create the custom supplementary view cell.

   ```
   - (headerCollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionViews viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       UICollectionReusableView *reusableView = nil;

       if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {

           UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"headerCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil];

           [collectionViews registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"headerCell"];

           headerCollectionViewCell *collectionHeader = [collectionViews dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"headerCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
           collectionHeader.titleLabel.text = @"What";

           reusableView = collectionHeader;
      }

      return reusableView;
   }
   ```

Comment: You're using `registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:`. You should be using `registerNib:forSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:`

Comment: Use cells for the grid items and supplementary views for headers/footers. More [here](http://nshipster.com/uicollectionview/#supplementary-views). Also, [this post](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12) is a bit old, but it has some good diagrams and examples of semantic uses of the different elements of the UICollectionView. Hope that clears it up a bit.

Comment: And with adding this to viewDidLoad you do not have to add it again in delegate function. 10x @gabriel-osorio you are right.

Comment: Please Andrew edit your answer, without Gabriel's comment it's useless.

Comment: Please use below code for Header and Footer view in UICollectionView
`[self.selectionCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FlootThumbnailCollectionReusableView" bundle:nil]   forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView"];`

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if someone needs solution. 
You don't have to register the header class using

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:...]
```

Just use the layout's delegate method to return the header class.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is can be few reasons:

1. (most common)
   If u add u'r `suplementaryView` in storyboard, and then try to register class

   ```
   [self.stickyCollectionView registerClass:[<CLASSFORSUPPLEMENTARYVIEWW> class]
             forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
                    withReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([<CLASSFORSUPPLEMENTARYVIEWW> class])];
   ```

u will get `suplementaryView`, but not that u create (standard one) - u will see obj, but actually this is will be like placeholder.

Example:

[image]

Here u can see that obj was created, but outlets are nil (in this simple case only one outlet - `_monthNameLabel`).

2. I see few times this problem also

If u create separate `Obj` for handling dataSourse/delegate for `collectionView` and add reference outlet to it, and in `init` methods try to register class to u'r outlet (assumed that view created in separate nib file), u will also receive same result like previous, but reason another - u'r outlet is nil here:

[image]

As solution u for example can use custom setter for this like:

```
#pragma mark - CustomAccessors

- (void)setcCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    _collectionView = collectionView;

    [self.stickyCollectionView registerNib:...];
}
```

3. as suggested by @Anil Varghese

u can use `registerClass` instead of `registerNib`

Answer (score 1):

**Xcode 9, Swift 4:**

Register `UICollectionReusableView` in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "DashBoardCollectionReusableView", bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "ReuseIdentifier")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class CustomFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let attributesForElementsInRect = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
        var newAttributesForElementsInRect = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        for attributes in attributesForElementsInRect! {

            if !(attributes.representedElementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
                || attributes.representedElementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter) {

                // cells will be customise here, but Header and Footer will have layout without changes.
            }

            newAttributesForElementsInRect.append(attributes)
        }

        return newAttributesForElementsInRect
    }
}


class YourViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let headerNib = UINib.init(nibName: "HeaderCell", bundle: nil)
        collectionView.register(headerNib, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderCell")

        let footerNib = UINib.init(nibName: "FooterCell", bundle: nil)
        collectionView.register(footerNib, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "FooterCell")
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        switch kind {
        case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
            let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderCell", for: indexPath) as! HeaderCell
            return headerView
        case UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter:
            let footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "FooterCell", for: indexPath) as! FooterCell
            return footerView
        default:
            return UICollectionReusableView()
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 45)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 25)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You was registering correctly the class and the delegate is implemented correctly.

The problem can be that the flow layout (by default) is not configured for header view, do you have this line in the code or interface file?

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)_collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
flowLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(_collectionView.bounds), 100);
```